# What's the best way to manage the EF context in a three layer architecture with WebApi 2.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create an API architecture using *WebApi 2.0* and *Entity Framework 6.0* and I want to be near to the best practices so here is what I have atm.

[image: Solution architecture]

- **API** is an *Azure API* template and have references to **BusinessLogic** and **Domain**
- **BusinessLogic** is a *Class Library* and have references to **DataAccess** and **Domain**
- **DataAccess** is a *Class Library* and have a reference to **Domain** (also there are here the EF references)

I have edited the T4 template in **DataAccess** to generate *POCO* classes in **Domain** project and alterated the namespaces generation to acomplish that.
At this point it's all ok but my big concern is related to the layer independence regarding this architecture and EF model context.

What I know (let me know if I'm wrong in anyone):

1. Have a shared model context (singleton pattern) with the EF context in a WebApi is a bad practice.
2. The only place where I should have EF context object is in **Domain**
3. Any request to the API who generate a db interaction should create its independent EF Model context (independent from other request) but try to use the same context along the all db interactions at this particular request.

So thinking on that, what's the best way to manage the *EF context* in a three layer architecture with *WebApi 2.0*

Answer (score 2):

The DataAccess layer has the purpose of abstract the domain of the data persistence. EF is an ORM, so the EF itself is a kind of DataAccess library. Maybe you could still have the separations having repository implementations for you domain objects inside DataAccess project.

About your questions:

1) Yes, DbContext is a transient object.

2) EF POCO classes as Domain Objects is a bad practice. Domain objects shouldn't be anemic. They need to have logic. In the other hand, mix the domain objects with additional properties, sometimes required by ORMs (NHibernate, EF) seems like you data access technology is leaked your domain model.

Why not use memento pattern (or state object) to avoid this leaks and use some kind of mapper library (maybe Automapper) between the communication of your layes using DTOs?

Another alternative is handle the translation between your Domain object and your persistence object be a responsability of your Repository, but this solution could be a violation of Single Responsability Principle. So you need to trade between have that responsability in the Domain object itself, move to repository, or have specific classes for that duty.

A third alternative could be the use of Interfaces.

The memento and Interface approaches are explained [here](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879)

3) In you introduce IoC pattern. Using Dependency Injection you could move the responsability of create a DbContext outside of both, your Domain project and your Data Access project. This kind of design allows you to do interesting things in your composition root, you could have a DbContext per Http Request.

Comment: The purpose of have a Domain projec with POCO classes generated by T4 template that I found is to share that classes along all the projects. Regarding to Anemic Domain Model I think is not a big deal because I'm planing to create partial classes to extend POCO classes functionality when it needed. I don't see the need to create in Domain different classes than generated by EF. I'm mixing concepts or you agree?

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, shared model context is bad practice, in this case you cannot use transactions for instance
2. Use POCO and make them as simple as possible, get rid of any extra dependencies like EF, ServiceModel and so on.
3. Your #3 is correct, use independent context for each API request. You can implement Unit of Work pattern to incapsulate DBContext and get rid of direct reference to EF from BusinessLogic assembly (see [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), it is about MVC but it is applicable in your case)

Comment: Why is the purpose of have Domain project, if the domain objects are POCO classes? This is a clever clase of Anemic Domain Model. A bad practice that should be avoided.

Comment: Sorry if I confuse you by terminology but I mean that POCO is class without extra dependencies, it is not inherited from EF base class. Of course it can contain required methods and properties. But in other hand, in original post we can see Business Logic library and author should split business logic and domain model correctly

Comment: I will see how to implement Unit of Work pattern but maybe I'm confused but EF don't have as itself the Unit of Work pattern? What's the benefit to implement my own?

Comment: Unit of Work pattern can help you to "try to use the same context along the all db interactions at this particular request"